# What is the purpose of the |$ within quotes in the following command?

Tags: regex

```
openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -noout -text | grep -Ei ".*public.*|$" | less -Rx
```

How does this command filter the information in bold?

```
Technical College, CN = Jim's Root CA
**Subject Public Key Info:
Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)**
Modulus:
00: bc: e9:14: f5:63:4b:30: d9:50:6a: 38:f6:5f:ae:
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*public.*|$` is a regular expression (regexp) that matches:

- `.*` : 0 or more any character
- `public` : literally "public", case insensitive because of the flag `-i` in grep options
- `|` : means OR
- `$` : end of line

It matches all lines that contain "public" within them or end of line

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/HsFQ9i/1)